# How to plot wide dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, seaborn

After training a model, I want to plot the accuracy, validation accuracy, etc. In Seaborn, this is what I tried to do:

```py
df_model_history = pd.DataFrame(
    np.array([
        history.history['accuracy'],
        history.history['val_accuracy']
    ]).T,
    columns=['Accuracy', 'Validation Accuracy']
)

df_model_history.index.name = 'Epochs'
```

That creates a data frame that looks like this:

| Epochs | Accuracy | Validation Accuracy |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 0.769296 | 0.766673 |
| 1 | 0.858553 | 0.894064 |
| 2 | 0.915641 | 0.901508 |
| 3 | 0.936782 | 0.892285 |

And when I want to plot, I do this:

```
sns.set(rc={'figure.figsize':(11.7,8.27)})

sns.lineplot(
    x='Epochs',
    y='Accuracy',
    data=df_model_history
)
```

However, this only plots a single variable in the figure, but I wanted both 'accuracy' and 'val_accuracy' in the same figure. Also, compared to Matplotlib, I have a lot more steps in Seaborn to plot the same output, so I was wondering if I'm doing it incorrectly.

Comment: [`.melt`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.melt.html) `'accuracy'` and `'validation accuracy'`, and then set `hue='name of new label column'`

Comment: `dfm = df.melt(id_vars='Epochs')` and `sns.lineplot(data=dfm, x='Epochs', y='value', hue='variable')`